# Component prop isn't reactive after initial router push (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have some views/components; Home, ScrapeResults, and Search. To help y'all follow what is going on, here are some snippets of code that are relevant to my issue.

Snippet of App.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app-bar>
        <Search @selected_card="scrape"/>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-content>
        <v-container fluid style="width: 80%;">
            <router-view :card="card"></router-view> //card prop is in ScrapeResults.vue
        </v-container>
    </v-content>
</template>

<script>
    data() {
        return {
           card: {}
        }
    }
    methods: {
        scrape(card) { //card parameter value is from $emit event from Search
            if(this.$router.currentRoute.name != 'scrape-results') {
                this.$router.push({name: 'scrape-results', params: { card: card } });
            }
            else {
                this.card = card;
                console.log(this.card)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Snippet of Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="home">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <Search id="search" @selected_card="scrape"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    methods: {
        scrape(card) { //card parameter value is from $emit event from Search
            this.$router.push({ name: 'scrape-results', params: { card: card } });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Snippet of ScrapeResults:

```
<template>
    <div id="home">
        <h1>Scrape Results</h1>
        <p> {{card.name}} - {{card.set_name}} </p>
        <v-img :src="card.img_url"></v-img>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    ...... //irrelevant stuff
    props: {
        card: Object
    },
    watch: {
        card() {
            console.log(this.card)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Paths within the app:

- / (Home)
- /scrape-results (ScrapeResults)

So how the app work is the user will search for a card (Object) and select from a rendered list. Once the user selects a card from the rendered list, then the user is redirected to the Scrape Results view. All of that works fine when done from Home.vue.

My issue: If the user accessed Scrape Results from Home.vue, and while still on Scrape Results view, if the user were to search for another card via the Search component that is mounted (in the app bar) in App.vue, then the card prop in ScrapeResults.vue doesn't update. The weird thing is that if I manually navigate to Scrape Results by entering /scrape-results in the address bar, search for a card via the Search component in the app bar, then the card prop updates. The card prop will only update if I manually access /scrape-results and then search for a card.

I know all of that sounds confusing, so here's a clip I recorded to that demonstrates what my issue is. Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aO9qSTa9CCk&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

EDIT: Route definition below

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home'
import ScrapeResults from '@/views/ScrapeResults'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router =  new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/scrape-results',
            name: 'scrape-results',
            component: ScrapeResults,
            props: true
        }
    ]
});

export default router;
```

Comment: show a route definition

Comment: @Anatoly what do you mean by route definition?

Comment: The code where you create a router and register `/scrape-results` path

Comment: @Anatoly Oh, that. Sorry for not understanding. Edited post to show route definition.

Comment: In order to make 'params' work in a named router you should register a route like '/scrape-results/:card' with props: true

Comment: @Anatoly params still work if I just register the path as /scrape-results. I search from Home, it goes to ScrapeResults and it displays the card information fine. The issue is if I want to search for more cards after that from the navbar, the prop doesn't update. The issue is demonstrated in the video that I provided.

Comment: @Anatoly, I fixed it by changing the path to /scrape-results/:card_set/:card_name and pushed extra params. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of trying to make passing a prop to router-view work, I just ended up changing the ScrapeResults path in my router.js to /scrape-results/:card_set/:card_name; original was just /scrape-results. I then just pushed extra params in $router.push

```
this.$router.push({name: 'scrape-results', params: { card: card, card_set: card.set_name, card_name: card.name } });
```